# Reading a pivot table that was created by pandas from exported csv

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I created a `pivot table` using `pandas` and saved it as a `csv` using `DataFrame.to_csv`.

When I try to load it back using `pd.read_csv()` the columns hierarchy is not preserved and the column names appear as values.

Is there a generic way to reconstruct it, or am I supposed to write something on my own that is tailored to my specific case?

For example, the beginning of the file looks like this:
type,X,Y,Y

score,50,50,90

item,,,

a,1,,

b,1,,

c,1,,

d,1,,

e,1,,

f,,1,1

when i try reading it, it looks like this:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('tempip.csv')
    df
    type     X     Y   Y.1
0  score  50.0  50.0  90.0
1   item   NaN   NaN   NaN
2      a   1.0   NaN   NaN
3      b   1.0   NaN   NaN
4      c   1.0   NaN   NaN
5      d   1.0   NaN   NaN
6      e   1.0   NaN   NaN
7      f   NaN   1.0   1.0
```

But originally type was a parent column to score (so X had one score, 50, and Y had 50 and 90) and item was the index column.

Comment: Could you post the code you used please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too vague, please add a code sample of what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Edited my question so you can see the sample @JackHanson

Comment: The pandas module might help. There's a transpose function that can flip the columns and rows, but without a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't try anything specific to help. Also, if you have two y values, you'll have to look at the "non- square dataframe" section of transpose. Check the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)